# ruby on rails:How to get formatted message on text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've asked this question about getting formatted text in text field but didn't get the answer that I could yet use practically.

[ruby on rails: text filed formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279517/ruby-on-rails-text-filed-formatting/39279636?noredirect=1#comment65896277_39279636)

I've used tutorial by Michael Harti.

would you please advice what I need to change or add in my code to get formatted message in the text field?
thanks.

Comment: You can use ckeditor:  https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: I download it and it in my application folder

Any particular hints/advices/directions to follow how to install it in my ruby on rails framework?

Comment: Installation instructions are provided with the gem. What more do you want?

Comment: There is no problem in install gem but I am not sure how to change existing files to make formatting. I've provided gists with files that has text area(see link in the post), So, I need to figure  out how to keep functionality existing files and game the new formatting option. 
If you know the answer, you could put your answer include the code related instead of comments.