# CKEditor: how to get clcikable links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’ve followed Michael Harti Ruby on Rails tutorial and created ruby on rails app.
I’ve added some functionality as formatted text (link below) by  implementing SKEditor.

[ruby on rails: text filed formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279517/ruby-on-rails-text-filed-formatting)

So, right now text formatting is fine but the links are not clickable.

I mean, when users  type for ex,   http:://www/yahoo.com,  they could not just click on it and go to yahoo.page. - it is just text instead of links.

I use

https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

and  followed installation until Advanced Usage
to get formatted text.

How to make link clickable?

Advanced Usage said

“Add your app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js.coffee like..”

But right now, in my frame I have only app/assets/stylesheets…..

I create folder ckeditor and put file contents.css.scss and  other files as well on it follow Advance Usage CKEditor(link above).

Is it right approach or should I do something differently?

But after those adding, I still have no clickable links……

How to get clcikable links using CKEditor

Thanks.

Comment: You mean CKeditor not SKeditor right ?

Comment: CKeditor has a tool to add hyperlink which wraps the text with anchor tag `<a></a>` .By default everything is string and won't get converted into link

Comment: Yes, I've changed.. thanks.

Comment: how to use this tool on CKEditor? I've tried just wrap text using <a></a> but it doesn't  work....

Comment: No if you wrap text with anchor tag that will still get saved as a plain text. You just need to click on link sign which is present on top of editor that's it

Comment: Are you able to see the editor ?

Comment: yes, I could see it but I don't know how to post screen shot here of CKEditor..

Comment: You can upload the image here on SO or use some third party image hosting site and share the link

Comment: I think I've figured it out. it is works. it get https and I added www.yahoo.com. - and it is clickable  but could I put instead of this just clickable one word "News"?

Comment: That exactly I was suggesting by using the tool provided by ckeditor you can make a word clickable

Comment: how to upload the image here on SO ?

Comment: yes it works. But could  I get clickable not  all link but part of it, for ex. I don't want that user see "www.yahoo.com" but could see for ex "News" and could click on it? the same way as could be done on html page...

Comment: Yes is it quite possible, first select the text written inside editor text area then click on link sign on the toolbar and add link. this should just add link to the text selected.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the image below, I have first selected a text then clicked on link sign present at the second row of toolbar and finally added a link. 
hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is help. Also, the color of link could be change as well.